# Is it possible to have a child bone follow a parent bone's movement ONLY in the ground plane via IK?

Tags: armature, bones

Is it possible to have two bones, B1 and B2 (child of B1), such that B1 can move/rotate in any direction but B2 can ONLY move along the XY (ground) plane?

In practice, I would like to parent "B2" to a bone ("center") which controls a model's position including vertical height (e.g. if they're squatting or jumping), and attach a collision body to "B2" to prevent parts of the model's outfit from sinking through the floor. (My extra challenge will be to figure out how to translate this to my specific modeling program, but I'll try to figure that out myself.)

EDIT: Thanks to MoonBoots, I know that Limit Constraint works within Blender, but this doesn't export to my target program. At risk of expanding my question beyond original constraints, is what I seek possible with IK?

Comment: have you tried the Limit Location constraint?

Comment: I thought I had something for a sec, but this only appeared to work because B2 wasn't parented to B1. Adding a Limit Location with min/max Z=0 to B2 doesn't appear to keep that bone in the ground plane if I move B1 up. (I am very inexperienced with making armatures in Blender.)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is an IK setup, and even then if the model "jumps" high enough, that wouldn't work. I could certainly account for expected vertical movements with such a setup, but is there a better way?

Comment: could you please test and see in what way it is not what you want? https://pasteall.org/blend/747665bb0777472bbb9bcd47d90c6057

Comment: ... Why did I have to delete my own test file; this seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks! Only thing is, that constraint doesn't export properly to my target program (which is the other half of this issue--I know this is slightly beyond the scope of my question), so is it possible to do what I want with IK (which the program does have)?

Comment: you mean that the parent bone has an IK constraint? Maybe someone will know how to do it with some codes?

Comment: I solved my issue with IKs. I'll post both as answers because even if yours doesn't help me for my export program, it does for anyone seeing this who only wants to use Blender. Thank you!

Comment: yes please explain what solution you've found with the Ik

Comment: ... Maybe I didn't after all. What I found via IKs does keep the B2 bone at ground level if I move B1 vertically, but (1) B2 is the IK target and rotates whenever B1 moves, and (2) the mesh I attached does not move at all in the X or Y directions.